# How to set hotkeys for a Windows Forms form

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to set hotkeys in my Windows Forms form. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> for a new form and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for save. How would I do this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Set

```
myForm.KeyPreview = true;
```

Create a handler for the *[KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* event:

```
myForm.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form_KeyDown);
```

Example of handler:

```
    // Hot keys handler
    void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)       // Ctrl-S Save
        {
            // Do what you want here
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;  // Stops other controls on the form receiving event.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh you are correct. I forgot to set the `KeyPreview` property, which is necessary for this case. +1.

Comment: Great answer. Note that with newer C# registering events became easier, e.g. `this.KeyDown += (object sender, KeyEventArgs e) => Form_KeyPress(sender, e, true); this.KeyUp += (object sender, KeyEventArgs e) => Form_KeyPress(sender, e, false);` will create **one**  handler named `Form_KeyPress` handling KeyDown and KeyUp at the same time - with an additional bool variable telling the handler if key is pressed or released. Its signature is: `Form_Press(object sender, KeyEventArgs e, bool pressed) { ... }`

Answer (score 7):

You can also override `ProcessCmdKey` in your `Form` derived type like this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message message, Keys keys)
{
    switch (keys)
    {
        case Keys.B | Keys.Control | Keys.Alt | Keys.Shift:
            // ... Process Shift+Ctrl+Alt+B ...

            return true; // signal that we've processed this key
    }

    // run base implementation
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref message, keys);
}
```

I believe it's more suitable for hotkeys. No `KeyPreview` needed.

Answer (score 6):

If your window has a menu, you can use the `ShortcutKeys` property of `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem`:

```
myMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control | Keys.S;
```

In Visual Studio, you can set it in the property page of the menu item, too.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like a `KeyDown` event for the Form and some code like this:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.N))
    {
        CreateNew();
    }
}
```

Comment: can anyone please tell me what is this CreateNew()?Is it a built in function?

Comment: @riya7887: It's just an example. It's not a built in method. You can create such a method and put all the related code in.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to link them to menu items in your application, then you don't need any code.  On the menu item, you can simply setup the shortcut key property and it will run the same event that you have configured for your menu item click.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd put an update here since the newest answer is 5 years old.  Specifically addressing the question portion regarding Menu hotkeys, you can manipulate the properties of your `MenuStrip.MenuItem` object, by setting the `ShortcutKeys` property.  In Visual Studio you can do this in the form design window by opening the properties of your `MenuStrip` object.  Once scrolled down to the the `ShortcutKeys` property, you can use VS interface to set your hot keys.

[image]

If you want a `MenuStrip` to underline a menu item, prefix the ampersand (&) char to the char of the desired hotkey.  So for example if you want the "x" of Exit to be underlined, the property setting should be `E&xit`.

[image]

These property manipulations should yield a result similar to this*:
[image]

***Note**: To display the shortcut key "Ctrl+N" change `ShowShortcutKeys` property to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to handle the [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, and then you can start watching out for your modifiers:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
    {
        //Do whatever
    }
}
```

Of course, you need to make sure your form subscribes to the KeyDown event.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it using a hidden menu too, if you want. Just set the property of menu.visible = false;