# Create Short Cut on Web Page for Save Delete

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Can i create short cut for save and delete button click or event on web page in asp.net if i press cnt + a or d it will trigger the save and delete event or ajax call something in web form and submit form data like we can do in windows application

Can any one help me.

Comment: what do you mean by short cut? if you provide some code it will help better understand what you are trying to ask

Comment: means on web page there is save and delete button if i press cnt + d it will delete the data and if i press cnt + a it will save the data on web page

Comment: oh oh I see what you're saying, you want key press event handlers for specific key press combinations. I'm pretty sure you can do this in JavaScript/JQuery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set hotkeys for a Windows Forms form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048748/how-to-set-hotkeys-for-a-windows-forms-form)

Comment: ok so i can do this with javascript or jquery. i have to create event handler for that on Onload or Document.Ready function

Comment: yeah there are many ways (languages) to capture the keyboard key presses and respond appropriately

Comment: ok i got, i will try to do how to create hotkey with jquery

Comment: thanks you @aquaballin

Comment: yeah no problem, you should be able to do this in either JavaScrip/Jquery or C#, its up to you