# How can I send a keystroke to some other windows application?

Tags: c#, winforms

In this part from a class I'm capturing all the windows of a working processes:

```
private static bool EnumWindowsCallback(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            bool specialCapturing = false;

            if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) return false;

            if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;

            if (!countMinimizedWindows)
            {
                if (IsIconic(hWnd)) return true;
            }
            else if (IsIconic(hWnd) && useSpecialCapturing) specialCapturing = true;

            if (GetWindowText(hWnd) == PROGRAMMANAGER) return true;

            if (GetWindowText(hWnd).Contains("Test"))
                windowSnaps.Add(new WindowSnap(hWnd, specialCapturing));

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the collection of WindowSnap instances fro all available windows
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="minimized">Capture a window even it's Minimized</param>
        /// <param name="specialCapturring">use special capturing method to capture minmized windows</param>
        /// <returns>return collections of WindowSnap instances</returns>
        public static WindowSnapCollection GetAllWindows(bool minimized, bool specialCapturring)
        {
            windowSnaps = new WindowSnapCollection();
            countMinimizedWindows = minimized;//set minimized flag capture
            useSpecialCapturing = specialCapturring;//set specialcapturing flag
            EnumWindowsCallbackHandler callback = new EnumWindowsCallbackHandler(EnumWindowsCallback);
            EnumWindows(callback, IntPtr.Zero);

            return new WindowSnapCollection(windowSnaps.ToArray(), true);
        }
```

In the end I have in the windowSnaps for example two items two windows of applications name Test.

In Form1:

```
private void buttonSnap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.listBoxSnap.Items.Clear();
            this.pictureBoxSnap.Image = null;
            this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange
                (
            WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(this.checkBoxMinimized.Checked, this.checkBoxSpecialMode.Checked).ToArray()
                );
        }
```

Now In the listBox(listBoxSnap) I want to do that when I select one of the items for example the item in index 0 send automatic to this application the keystroke. For example send to this specific application window the keystroke ctrl+s but without bringing the application window to the front or focus it.

UPDATE what I tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MinimizeCapture
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        // windows messages
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

        // "Ctrl key" virtual key-code
        const int VK_CONTROL = 0x11;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonSnap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.listBoxSnap.Items.Clear();
            this.pictureBoxSnap.Image = null;
            this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange
                (
            WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(this.checkBoxMinimized.Checked, this.checkBoxSpecialMode.Checked).ToArray()
                );
        }

        private void listBoxSnap_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowSnap snap = this.listBoxSnap.SelectedItem as WindowSnap;

            this.pictureBoxSnap.Image = snap.Image;


            SetForegroundWindow(snap.Handle);

            // hWnd is a handle of a window which should receive Ctrl+S
            SendMessage(snap.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, 0);
            SendMessage(snap.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)'s', 0);
            SendMessage(snap.Handle, WM_KEYUP, (int)'s', 0);
            SendMessage(snap.Handle, WM_KEYUP, VK_CONTROL, 0);

        }
```

The line:

```
SetForegroundWindow(snap.Handle);
```

Bringing the selected window to the front but the ctrl+s not seems to be effecting the window at all.

Comment: It's not a hotkey. It is a way to emulate key press by code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set hotkeys for a Windows Forms form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048748/how-to-set-hotkeys-for-a-windows-forms-form)

Comment: SendKeys is not a hotkey. It does exactly what the name says - it sends a keystroke, now, immediately when it executes.

Comment: It's working but I forgot to mention in my question that I need it to be global. The solution in the link is working only when the form it in the front.

Comment: ok, now we know, that you need a hotkey. Next, are you sure you need a **Global** hotkey? It is realy strange to register a global Ctrl+S, maybe you need a kind of **Application-wide** hotkey?

Comment: What I need my main goal is to capture a window application( I did it already) And now somehow I want to make that when I select the captured window in a listbox to send to this application the ctrl+s like a command line. It's not realy that I will press on ctrl+s but the program should send it automatic to the selected application window in the list box.

Comment: My project a bit long but I can add the important stuff to my question.

Comment: oh, so you actualy need to **send** a keystroke to some other (not yours) windows application? If so, you realy should edit your question to show this info:\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far, as I can see from your comments, you need to send a `Ctrl+S` keystroke to another window. If so, you need to use [SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) WinAPI with [WM_KEYDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-keydown) and [WM_KEYUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-keyup) messages.

I assume you already know, how to get window handle, so check this code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);

// windows messages
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

// "Ctrl key" virtual key-code
const int VK_CONTROL = 0x11;

// hWnd is a handle of a window which should receive Ctrl+S
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, 0);
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)'s', 0);
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, (int)'s', 0);
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_CONTROL, 0);
```

**Please note**: window, that should receive this messages must be in focus!

Comment: Not working even when bringing the selected window to the front to be focus. Updated my question with what I did.

Comment: It's strange:\ can you try add some delay between `SendMessage()` calls?