# How can I make Hotkey control at C# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#

I am making C# WinForm app with Visual Studio. I have used AutoHotKey and AHK had GUI control named 'Hotkey Box'(AutoGUI said 'Hotkey Box').

When a user clicks at 'Hotkey Box' and enters a combination of hotkey like 'Ctrl+Alt+F', It appeared inside the box. Like this:

[image]

And I want to use this kind of control so that user can easily make their own hotkey.

[image]

If user has to select each key in the dropdown list, it will be very uncomfortable.

I searched google, but only found information that I have to use `msctls_hotkey32` thing. I could not find how to use `msctls_hotkey32`.

And since I have to use that control in Designer Mode to adjust position/width/etc. How can I use my custom control in Designer Mode?

Comment: This post may be able to help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048748/how-to-set-hotkeys-for-a-windows-forms-form

Comment: @Joshk326 I'm not asking about 'how to make hotkey'. I'm asking about 'how to make hotkey control box or hotkey box'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a custom control of your own and then override the following on the custom control,

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
  get
  {
    CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
    cp.ClassName = "msctls_hotkey32";
    return cp;
  }
}
```

[CreateParams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.createparams) is called when the control handle is created

Comment: I tried to make my own control like this: [imgur album](https://imgur.com/a/XhJHtbf) and got error that VS cannot load my control and will remove from tool box. What am I doing wrong? [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ay4xu6N2)

Comment: Is the base type Control or TextBox?

Comment: It is kind of TextBox that shows user-entered hotkey like 'Control + Shift + F12'

Comment: Any chance you can share the custom control's designer code?

Comment: I gave up using 'msctls_hotkey32'. instead, I made custom class that inherit TextBox and set event listeners to mimic what Hotkey Control. I used code from stackoverflow but I can't find the article I used code from.  
It seems not working as I intended to but here is the code I am working on. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/9E8awEYQ)